# @Order with @Bean annotated method behaviour

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-bean

My configuration class:

```
@Bean(name = "model")
@Order(1)
public Model model1(){
    return new Model(1);
}

@Bean(name = "model")
@Order(2)
public Model model2(){
    return new Model(2);
}
```

As we can see, the two methods create a Bean with the same name, I have used the `@Order()` annotation to give priority to one of the beans.

Unfortunately, even if I change the value of the Order to alter between the two annotated Beans, **Only the first Bean is used** in my code below:

```
 Model bean = (Model) applicationContext.getBean("model");
 System.out.println("bean.getId() "+bean.getId());
```

> bean.getId() 1

Do we have two beans on the context? if we have only one, which of the two will be chose and why?

I know that I can use different names to differentiate between the beans, but I'm willing to understand how the `@Order` annotation works in parallel with `@Bean`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Spring 4 you can get [List of Bean](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-order) ordered by precedence.

```
@Autowired
private List<Model> models;
```

And in your method get by index

```
 models.get(0).getModel();
```

> Since Spring 4.0, it supports the ordering of injected components to a collection. As a result, Spring will inject the auto-wired beans of the same type based on their order value.